# Javascript Interacative graph

Tags: javascript, jqplot

Good evening. I'm trying to create an interactive graph. By "interactive graph" I mean:

For example I have a fixed size coordinate system: `x = (0,10), y = (-2, 2)`

And I want to plot a function of time, for example `f(t) = sin(t)`, where `x = t, y = f(t)`

But because of my fixed size coordinate system I will be able to see `sin(t)` only till `t <= 10`

Does JavaScript has library which would shift graph not changing size of coordinate system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) and [CanvasJS](http://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-dynamic-chart/) solved my problem.